# Codeigniter Undefined method 'getGet'.intelephense(1013)

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, codeigniter-4

I just installed Codeigniter 4.1.1, the installation process went smoothly without warning
but there are some functions that my VSCode doesn't detect, they are getGet(), getPost(), getVar() and all other incomingRequest functions.
even though the function works well in version 4.0.x, but why can't it for 4.1.x?

By the way, even though there is a warning in the above function, the program can still be run, but the warning is annoying to see

Screenshot my VSCode: https://prnt.sc/z2pevk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the accepted answer works fine, it's not a good practice to edit `vendor` files because the next time you run `composer update` or `composer install` all those changes will be undone.

Hence, the `vendor` folder shouldn't be touched.

Back to the context of the question, the reason behind this error is that `RequestInterface` enforces ONLY the following methods to be implemented by the class:

- `getIPAddress(): string`
- `isValidIP(string $ip, string $which = null): bool`
- `getMethod(bool $upper = false): string`
- `getServer($index = null, $filter = null)`

CodeIgniter `Controllers` folder usually contains a `BaseController` class which all other controllers inherits from, so what you can do is to simply re-define the `$request` data member there as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest; // ADD THIS LINE
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Class BaseController
 *
 * BaseController provides a convenient place for loading components
 * and performing functions that are needed by all your controllers.
 * Extend this class in any new controllers:
 *     class Home extends BaseController
 *
 * For security be sure to declare any new methods as protected or private.
 */

class BaseController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Instance of the main Request object.
     *
     * @var IncomingRequest
     */
    protected $request; // NOTICE THIS LINE AND THE COMMENT ABOVE IT

    /**
     * An array of helpers to be loaded automatically upon
     * class instantiation. These helpers will be available
     * to all other controllers that extend BaseController.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $helpers = [];

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param RequestInterface  $request
     * @param ResponseInterface $response
     * @param LoggerInterface   $logger
     */
    public function initController(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        // Do Not Edit This Line
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Preload any models, libraries, etc, here.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // E.g.: $this->session = \Config\Services::session();
    }
}
```

What we've done is to simply switch the type from `RequestInterface` to `IncomingRequest` which contains implementations of methods defined in `RequestInterface` plus additional methods defined by the class.

Please notice, that the access modifier for the `$request` data member needs to be `protected` since other controllers will inherites this controller.

As for CodeIgniter v4.1.2, this problem has been solved by the framework by applying a similar solution to the aforementioned one ((more details available at [Github diff link](https://github.com/codeigniter4/appstarter/commit/a0c857af31c1074b28d679c2dde6955138eec066#diff-2afdfe619fd918a59555251b2bd05871d71fc60c0df2ebe4213aeaa999682057)))

I hope i have given a good and detailed explanation.

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer; do not modify files within `vendor`. It's worth noting that this change was made to the `appstarter` repo; updating the `framework` (via Composer or otherwise) won't update the `BaseController` file already deployed to your `<root>/app/Controllers` directory. Existing projects deployed using the `appstarter` repo prior to v4.1.2 will need to manually update this file.

Comment: Yes this helped me solve it

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot, you are inspecting the methods of `$request` explicitly declared as `RequestInterface` and this interface only has the four methods showed in the IntelliSense. It works because the class that implements that interface has the methods that you are looking for.

I don't have VS Code here but I think you will find what you are looking for if try  `$this->request` because besides being a reference for the same object, it doesn't have an explicitly declared type.

The methods that you are looking to being shown are from `IncomingRequest` which extends `Request` and `Request` implement the `RequestInterface`.